# Use the same border as the TextBox for my control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, border, wpftoolkit

I have a custom **WpfToolkit DataGrid** (.net 3.5) that is always in edit mode and I would like it to have the same border as the standard TextBox.

I tried to:

1. bind the BorderBrush of my control to the BorderBrush of a TextBox (it seems the BorderBrush of the TextBox is null).
2. read the BorderBrush of a TextBox at runtime (it was always null).
3. I also tried to manually set a BorderBrush, but the TextBox has a
   different border brush depending on the Windows theme.

A normal TextBox border looks like this:

[image]

My control looks like this, but should have the same border as the text box:

[image]

EDIT:

my DataGrid cell style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:DataGridCell}" x:Key="DefaultExcelCell">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <!-- The text color of a selected cell (Black = same as not selected cell) -->
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look a the default `TextBox` style, you can figure out what is going on there. And i don't see why the `BorderBrush` of a `TextBox` at runtime is always null, it shouldn't be if the `TextBox` does not have another style applied.

```
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextBoxBorder" EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#ABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#E2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#E3E9EF" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Themes:ListBoxChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I did try this, but the problem is that each theme has a different border style. For example the above code will look fine in Windows 7 with the default theme, but in Windows Xp or in Windows 7 classic theme

Comment: There is a default style set for all the textBoxes in the program, but it does not set a BorderBrush, only things like Font, Font Size.

Comment: How do you customize the style for your cell in editing mode ? Have you tried setting the `TextBox` style to {x:Null} it should reset to default. I assume that the `WpfToolkit DataGrid` has defined some styles for some controls.

Comment: I used the CellStyle property of the WpfToolkit DataGrid to style the cell (no global style).

Comment: I also tried to figure out why BorderBrush was null, It seems I tried to access it to soon. It is there on the Loaded event, but unfortunately it has the wrong value if I don't use the aero theme (in windows 7).

Comment: Can you include your CellStyle `Style` in your question above ?

Comment: Sure, just edited the question. Notice that for some cells I set the style in code behind.